# Receiving error message TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null on previously working systems

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a few different systems that use the following code to access the underlying spreadsheets.

```
 var mainLinks = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main");
```

They have worked for 6 months, but I am now receiving the below error with a reference to the above line.

```
 TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null.
```

Has this method been changed?  Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has changed. You don't have a currently active spreadsheet. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) for `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet`

> Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.

So, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns `null`, because you have no currently active spreadsheet, then you try to call a method on null and get the expected error...

> Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null.

A simple fix to avoid the error would be to check for `null` like this

```
 var mainLinks;
 var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 if (activeSpreadsheet !== null) {
     mainLinks = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Main");
 } else {
     // handle case where there is no active spreadsheet
 }
```

There are many reasons that you might not have an active spreadsheet and we can't tell without more information, but you could try...

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(**your spreadsheet key**).getActiveSheet()
```

To find the spreadsheet key, open the spreadsheet and look at the browser address bar: the key is the bit between `key=` and the first non-alphanumeric character, usually a `&` or `#` as in `#gid` or `&pli=1`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a bit confused.  This is google app script that is bound to a spreadsheet with a web app that uses data from these sheets.  Shouldn't the bound spreadsheet be the active spreadsheet?

Comment: I just added a little suggestion to get your active spreadsheet to my answer. Hope it helps. Hard for me to help more without more information about your app

Comment: Thanks for you help. I used that work around to get our critical code/web apps working again.